# Save Uploaded image in canvas to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

We are fetching mask image from json & displaying in page. Once we click on mask, we are displaying file upload dialog box, so that user will upload the image.

[image]

**Requirement** :

Once user click on **save** button, i want to upload that image to server.... but now its not saving the image in server....

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/pXBRga

**Script** :

```
function test(){
var canvas  = document.getElementById("cvs");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 

});

}
```

**Upload.php** :

```
<?php    
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
imgBase64 = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Below is Snippet :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 400,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 20,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 20,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 500
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image
 
    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            var ImagePosition = arr;

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                
            };
            counter++;
        }       
        return mask;
    }

    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        const settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas            
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = ev.currentTarget;

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = $(item).attr("id");
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else
                    el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        
        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            if (settings.maskImage)
                context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                    .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;          
        }

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if (!isMask)
                container.data('image_set' + settings.id, true)
            return settings.id;
        };
          
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            // console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);
          
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };

        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

//Download image to server 

function test(){
var canvas  = document.getElementById("cvs");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 

});

}
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>

        
<br/>  
<button onclick="test()">Save image to server</button>
```

here is code in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MuJsxCHf)

Comment: one issue I see at first glance is in your .php file... imgBase64 should be $imgBase64 ... and I noticed you dont actually appear to USE that variable anywhere in the underlying php code.   In cases like this, for the PHP server side code I often times will inspect all the 'parts' im trying to use to make sure they are all working and in place -- echo each out to inspect, then I go back through the logic one step at a time.

Comment: @tamak Thanks  for suggestion , is it possible to save uploaded images in server without using php ? can we do with just html5, js or jquery ?

Comment: @vickeycolors No, javascript and html are not server-side languages. You will need a server side language to post to the server.

Comment: @vickeycolors - I have a working example l created a year or two ago -- I'll try to dig it up later today and show you the basics and give you a link to the github repo for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that some server-side language is necessary here... sure, you can (ajax) POST the base64 but something on the server has to know what to do with the POST(ed) data it receives.

Below is the PHP (server side code) I used on a previous project to allow the user to upload their own avatar image.

In my use case I have the ajax POST sending 3 things:

1. the users image file name
2. the users image file extension (png, jpg or gif)
3. the raw base64 encoding data

The PHP should be fairly self explanatory, but let me know if you have any questions.

You MAY need to make sure that the permissions on the folder where you're writing the image will in fact allow the PHP process to write.  Sometimes I've had to tweak folder permissions, just depends on the host platform configuration.

If it doesn't work, you can set PHP Errors to ON so it'll respond with details about what problems PHP is having.  (a quick google search should help with that).

You can simplify my example code with a single known file type and file name to do a quick test.  If you need help with it I might be able to connect with you via email to get details and assist.  (I remember how eager I was to get this working when I dealt with it -- I feel your pain!!!).

Updated PHP source code for the working solution:

```
if( isset($_POST['imgBase64']) && isset($_POST['imgFileName']) && 
isset($_POST['imgFileType']) ){

    $fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileName'); // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
    $img = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64');  // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
    $imgtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileType');  // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST

    // STRIP OFF THE BEGINNING OF THE BASE64 DATA, BUT DEPENDS ON THE IMAGE TYPE.  
    // I COULD HAVE SIMPLIFIED THIS BUT USED IF STATEMENTS.
    if ( $imgtype === 'png'){
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    };
    if ( $imgtype === 'jpg' || $imgtype === 'jpeg'){
        $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    };
    if ( $imgtype === 'gif'){
        $img = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $img);
    };

    // REPLACE ALL SPACES IN THE IMAGE DATA WITH PLUS SYMBOL
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img); 
    // CONVERT THE DATA FROM BASE64 ENCODING
    $img = base64_decode($img); 

    // SAVE THE FILE 
    file_put_contents('...path.../'.$fname, $img);


    echo '{"error":false, "message":"Image has been saved successfully!","data":[{"fileName": "'.$fname.'"}]}';
}
```

Comment: thanks , initially i tried your code with sample html code , but image is not uploading to server, also i am not getting any errors even i already added error reporting code in php....

Comment: thanks, your code worked fine, i can able to save the images in server, but saved images not displaying ,  please help me for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072987/can-not-open-uploaded-file-in-server

Comment: [Let us Continue the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196568/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-tamak)

Comment: @vickeycolors - i just updated source code answer above.  I've confirmed it works on your server and sent you an email.

Comment: Hi, Its saving uploaded image along with mask image, but what we need is to save only uploaded image, please help me for this as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089538/mask-image-uploaded-image-are-saving-in-server)....