# Pass Uploaded Image in document.getElementById instead of canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, html5-canvas

We are displaying box image & mask images by fetching json.

[image]

User will click on Mask image & upload their own image.

[image]

**Issue** :

Onclick Save button, Both mask image & user uploaded image are saving in server as below....

[image]

**Requirement** :

But Onclick Save button, i need to save only **user uploaded image** on server.

Below is User Uploaded image :

[image]

**Html**

```
<button class ="save" onclick="test()">Save image to server</button>
```

**Script**

```
function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: {
            imgBase64: dataURL,
            imgFileName: dataFileName,
            imgFileType: dataFileType
        }
    }).done(function(o, imgFileName) {

        console.log(o);
        var response = JSON.parse(o);
        console.log(response);

        $('body').prepend('<img src="' + dataFileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');

    });
}
```

**save.php**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['imgBase64']) && isset($_POST['imgFileName']) && isset($_POST['imgFileType'])) {

    $fname   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileName'); // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
    $img     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64'); // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
    $imgtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileType'); // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST   

    if ($imgtype === 'png') {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    };
    if ($imgtype === 'jpg') {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    };

    $imgtype = "png";

    $fn_array = explode(".",$fname);    
    unset($fn_array[count($fn_array)-1]);

    $fileName = join($fn_array).".".$imgtype;

    // REPLACE ALL SPACES IN THE IMAGE DATA WITH PLUS SYMBOL
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    // CONVERT THE DATA FROM BASE64 ENCODING
    $img = base64_decode($img);

    // SAVE THE FILE WITH NAME SYNTAX :
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/ecom1/site/test/save/' . $fileName, $img);


    echo '{"error":false, "message":null,"data":[{"msg": "Image has been saved successfully!", "fileName": "' . $fileName . '"}]}';
}
?>
```

Below is Full code in Snippet :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 200,
        "layers": [{
                "type": "image",
                "name": "bg_img",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 200,
                "height": 200,
                "src": "14IVyVb.png",
            },
            {
                "type": "image",
                "src": "l8vA9bB.png",
                "name": "mask_userimg",
                "x": 10,
                "y": 15,
                "width": 180,
                "height": 166
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 200
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);    
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            var ImagePosition = arr;

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                //document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                
            };
            counter++;
        }

        return mask;
    }

    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        const settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas            
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            if (settings.maskImage)
                context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                    .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if (!isMask)
                container.data('image_set' + settings.id, true)
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            // console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };

        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

//Download image to server 

function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "raju.php",
        data: {
            imgBase64: dataURL,
            imgFileName: dataFileName,
            imgFileType: dataFileType
        }
    }).done(function(o, imgFileName) {

        console.log(o);
        var response = JSON.parse(o);
        console.log(response);

        $('body').prepend('<img src="' + dataFileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');

    });
}
```

```css
.save {
font-size:20px;
} 
 
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:block">
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
    
<button class ="save" onclick="test()">Save image to server</button>
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/qeBNwK) , [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/xznerLw2/2/) , [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0CSEyim1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited that two files

**1. Javascript code**

```
var target;
const imageUrl = "";

var jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 200,
        "layers": [{
                "type": "image",
                "name": "bg_img",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 200,
                "height": 200,
                "src": "14IVyVb.png",
            },
            {
                "type": "image",
                "src": "l8vA9bB.png",
                "name": "mask_userimg",
                "x": 10,
                "y": 15,
                "width": 180,
                "height": 166
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 200
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;
let file;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        console.log(layer1);
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            var ImagePosition = arr;

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
                file = fileup.files[0];
                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                //document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                
            };
            counter++;
        }

        return mask;
    }

    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        const settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas            
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            if (settings.maskImage)
                context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                    .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if (!isMask)
                container.data('image_set' + settings.id, true)
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            // console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };

        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

//Download image to server 

function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('imgBase64', file, file.name);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save2.php",
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    }).done(function(o) {
        var response = JSON.parse(o);
        $('body').prepend('<img src="vikas2/images/' + response.data[0].fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');
    });
}
```

**2. save2.php**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (isset($_FILES['imgBase64'])) {

    $fname   = $_FILES["imgBase64"]["name"]; // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
    $img     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64'); // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
    $imgtype = $_FILES["imgBase64"]["type"]; // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST   

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgBase64"]["tmp_name"], "vikas2/images/".$fname)){
        echo '{"error":false, "message":null,"data":[{"msg": "Image has been saved successfully!", "fileName": "' . $fname . '"}]}';        
    }
    else{
        echo '{"error":true, "message":"File not uploaded"}';
    }
}
?>
```

Please check

Comment: its working perfect, thanks a ton..... can you please try with this code : https://pastebin.com/M1i45yiB , in that i have 2 mask images, but when user upload 2 images for 2 masks and click on `save` , its saving the latest user uploaded image, but  i want to save both user uploaded images also , please help me dynamically[ because in some cases i have 3 , 4 images  ....

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you upload the canvas not the user image:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
```

But you have to upload the selected image in the file input element. [Over here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata) is shown how to read the data from an file input element.

Comment: i thought when i use this line : `var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');` , then it will upload only `user uploaded image`......

Comment: Nope. that line only gets you the filename

Answer (score 1):

I update that two files

**1. text() - javascript function**

```
function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save2.php",
        data: {
            imgBase64: dataURL,
            imgFileName: dataFileName,
            imgFileType: dataFileType
        }
    }).done(function(o) {
        var response = JSON.parse(o);
        $('body').prepend('<img src="vikas2/images/' + response.data[0].fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');
    });
}
```

**2. save2.php**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['imgBase64']) && isset($_POST['imgFileName']) && isset($_POST['imgFileType'])) {

    $fname   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileName'); // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
    $img     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64'); // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
    $imgtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgFileType'); // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST   

    if ($imgtype === 'png') {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    };
    if ($imgtype === 'jpg') {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    };

    $imgtype = "png";

    $fn_array = explode(".",$fname);    
    unset($fn_array[count($fn_array)-1]);

    $fileName = join($fn_array).".".$imgtype;

    // REPLACE ALL SPACES IN THE IMAGE DATA WITH PLUS SYMBOL
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    // CONVERT THE DATA FROM BASE64 ENCODING
    $img = base64_decode($img);

    // SAVE THE FILE WITH NAME SYNTAX :
    file_put_contents('vikas2/images/' . $fileName, $img);


    echo '{"error":false, "message":null,"data":[{"msg": "Image has been saved successfully!", "fileName": "' . $fileName . '"}]}';
}
?>
```

It's saving user uploaded image

please try this

[image]

Comment: hi, its saving user uploaded images along with mask images, but  i want to save user uploaded images alone....

Comment: Multiple images at a time ?

Comment: no  please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196568/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-tamak